# What are e- and m-Riemann-Christoffel curvatures?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, riemann-surfaces, machine-learning, noneuclidean-geometry

Currently, I am going through [Information Geometry of Boltzmann Machines](http://www.maths.tcd.ie/~mnl/store/AmariKurataNagaoka1992a.pdf) by Amari et al.

In section III, the authors use the terms 'e- and m-Riemann-Christoffel curvatures'.

**My question**
What are the definitions of e- and m-Riemann-Christoffel curvatures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will find the answer ( or at least a starting point ) on page 38 of Amaris book.

Comment: you mean Methods of Information Geometry?

Comment: Yep, that's the one. Look out for the word exponential.